# Guaranteed prime solutions to congruence relations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p_1, p_2. ...,p_{x-1},  p_x$ be all of the the prime numbers from $2$ upto some arbitrarily chosen prime number $p_x$.

And consider the representation of a natural number $n$ in the form $(a_x, a_{x-1}, ..., a_2, a_1)$ where $a_y \equiv n \mod p_y$.

> If $n$ is a prime,
>
> $ n \equiv 0 \mod p_z$ iff $n = p_z$
>
> $ n \equiv a_z \mod p_z : a_z < n $ iff $p_z \leq n$
>
> $ n \equiv a_z \mod p_z: a_z = n$ iff $p_z > n$

My question is;

If we choose some arbitrary value of $x$, to give us a sort of base length for this representation of natural numbers in the way described above, and we chose random "digits", i.e we set some "random" congruence conditions; is it guaranteed that at least one prime number is the solution of our random congruence conditions if we make the rule that no "digit" can be $0$?.

For example, if I look at all numbers that are representable as (2,3,2,3,2,3,2,1), is there guaranteed to be a prime number that satisfies the respective system of congruence relations?

Obviously, we can use the Chinese remainder theorem to find solutions, but is there a proof that "one of the solutions must necessarily be a prime number" is True or False?

Comment: I don't understand the line $n\equiv a_z\pmod {p_z}\,:\, a_z=p_z\iff p_z>n$.  Are you saying that, for all $p_z>n$ you simply assign $a_z=p_z$ regardless of the exact value of $n$?  Perhaps an example would clarify things. Say $n=7$ and $x=6$, so the list of primes is $\{2,3,5,7,11,13\}$.  I'd have thought that $\{a_z\}=\{1,1,2,0,7,7\}$ but you appear to want $\{a_z\}=\{1,1,2,0,11,13\}$

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was a notational error. I meant what you expected.

Comment: Post edit, I think the following sketch ought to suffice:    Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to argue that, if you are given two arithmetic progressions $n\equiv a \pmod b$ and $n\equiv c \pmod d$ with $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(c,d)=\gcd( b,c)=1$ then their intersection is an arithmetic progression of the form $n\equiv f \pmod {bc}$ with $\gcd(f,bc)=1$.  Then apply Dirichlet to conclude.